# Which graph/network format should be used when releasing a data set?

Tags: data-visualization, data-mining, dataset, networks

Under [RENOIR](http://renoirproject.eu) (an EU funded project) I am working on releasing the data set of Slovenian Press Agency for researchers and other folk. As part of the data set we will be releasing some graphs with relationships of article similarity, keyword co-occurence and others. What should be the default format to release it for? I'm looking for something that works for text/network data scientists across different environments - python, java, R, scala etc. Should I go with CSV edgelists, or something more extensive like GML/GraphML?

Comment: Can you just confirm you mean mathematical graphs not statistical graphs? You use of network does imply that but best to be sure.

Comment: Yes I'm writing about mathematical graphs and empirically obtained networked data.

Answer (score 1):

As a consumer, I would prefer the commonest possible format, so that it can be processed by more tools. If you need the meta-data and extra expressiveness of things like GraphML, use that. If not, use a pair of CSV files, one for edges and one for nodes. Or one CSV file is there's no additional node information besides their occurrences in the edge list.